# Is there a way to validate that one checkbox is checked in Flask?

Tags: python, checkbox, jinja2, flask-wtforms

I am trying to create a Flask Form that include multiple checkboxes. However, I want to make sure that the user has at least one checkbox checked out of a group of about 30 checkboxes. Is it possible to do in Flask?

This is the Python Code for 3 of the buttons

```
button1 = BooleanField('button1')
button2 = BooleanField('button2')
button3 = BooleanField('button3')
```

This is the Jinja2 code for 3 of the buttons

```
{{ form.button1(class="form-checkbox-input") }}
{{ form.button1.label(class="form-check-label") }}<br>
{{ form.button2(class="form-checkbox-input") }}
{{ form.button2.label(class="form-check-label") }}<br>
{{ form.button3(class="form-checkbox-input") }}
{{ form.button3.label(class="form-check-label") }}<br>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
button1 = BooleanField('button1')
button2 = BooleanField('button2')
button3 = BooleanField('button3')
```

This is a rather inefficient (in the sense of what you have to write, not speed of your code) way to handle arrays. You might want to consider using an *actual* array, something like<sup>(a)</sup>:

```
buttonArray = []
for idx in range(30):
    # F-strings relatively recent Python, you could go back
    # to "button%d".format(idx + 1) if need be.

    buttonArray.append(BooleanField(f'button{idx + 1}'))
```

Then you could just use this to check if one or more is true:

```
if any(buttonArray):
    atLeastOneTrue()
```

and something like this to process each true element:

```
for idx in range(len(buttonArray)):
    if buttonArray[idx]:
        print(f'button{idx + 1} is true')
```

---

<sup>(a)</sup> Keep in mind I have very little knowledge of Jinja2 but it wouldn't surprise me if you could make them arrays at *that* point to make it even *more* efficient.